# Cross origin error in jquery.load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to load html snippets into my html page with the following code:

```
       <div data-include="header"></div>

        <script>
          $(function(){
            var includes = $('[data-include]');
            jQuery.each(includes, function(){
              var file = '_HTML/' + $(this).data('include') + '.html';
              $(this).load(file);
            });
          });
        </script>
```

In Firefox and Safari it works perfect, but in Chrome and IE Edge it gives me a cross origin request error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///../header.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Are there any workarounds for this error which are working in every of the named browsers?

Comment: have you tried adding `http://` or `https://`  (whichever suits your need) at the beginning of the URI ? This has already solved a similar issue in my case.

Comment: So what you are saying is two browsers properly protected you from malicious code and the other two didn't. and now you want to stop the first two from protecting you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need an http server to request local files.

You can start one easily using python:

```
python -m http.server 8000
```

Comment: @empiric i mean... python, iis, node.js, apache, nginx, etc, take your pick

Comment: @empiric and, yes, you do in fact need a server if you're going to test ajax requests without reducing the security of your web browser.

Comment: 1) As @KevinB said, you can use whatever you want to start an http server, just exemplified what I find simpler.

2) You're right, you do not need a server to open an html file, but you need a server to accept the http request from the html file. Chrome and Edge do not support the "file" type of request, I believe this is for security reasons.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your answer Murilo to make clear there are multiple solutions (different servers) and they are needed because of the security restrictions by some browsers.